# Visual Studio 2015 code map external dependencies

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, code-map

I have a native Win32 project written in C and wanted to visualize my project's dependencies from external DLLs. Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 let me generate a code map which would not only show all my functions and their dependencies from each other using arrows, but also all external libraries I used, which functions I used from those and which of my functions called which external functions etc..

Now, in Visual Studio 2015, this latter part seems to be missing. I can not get Visual Studio to show my project's external dependencies. I only see the internal ones. So here's my questions: Am I missing something? Do I have to activate a specific option in my project settings? Or are those external dependencies just not working in Visual Studio 2015 right now?

Steps to reproduce: Create a new non-empty Win32-project. In the **Architecture** menu, select **Generate code map for solution**. You will only see Win32Project1.exe in the middle of the screen. Meanwhile, Visual C# seems to be fine, showing the external dependencies. Create any C#-project for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for taking the time to post this! This looks like a regression, as in Visual Studio 2013 an Externals group with external dependencies is shown for C++.

I've logged a bug on Microsoft Connect so that you're able to track this externally:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1694695

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this workaround on the link that Bogdan Gavril listed and hope it helps someone.  Unfortunately, it requires that you enable "CLR" support for your project.  Basically, it appears that the VC++ linker and librarian is looking for a flag that indicates some type of managed code.  At the very least, the code map is dependent on the `mscorlib.dll` reference injection.  To make the CLR issue (which adds a lot of unnecessary bulk for native code) less a problem, simply create a new build configuration for use only when you need code maps with external dependencies.  Make sure you've selected "CLR Support" on the general options of the project properties configuration page.  Then, clean (probably not necessary) your solution and generate a code map.  You will find the external dependencies as expected!

Zac